# Validate three fields to check duplication

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to verify details from DB, either this call is available in DB or not. This code is working but for only 1st row, for example, ID is 123 CLI - 567 and duration is 00:01:00 is already available, and 2nd call duration is 00:01:01 is also available. But this code is not check the 2nd row and taking me to else statment.

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test");
$check="SELECT * FROM eval WHERE empid = '$_POST[empid]' AND cli = '$_POST[cli]'  AND callduration = '$_POST[callduration]' ";
$rs = mysqli_query($con,$check);
$data = mysqli_fetch_array($rs, MYSQLI_NUM);

if($data > 0 ) {
   echo "Record already exist...<br/>";
}
else
{
  echo "<a href='NewUser.php'> New Sign Up </a>
}
?>
```

Comment: try using echo $check and try it in db

Comment: due to `if($data > 0 ) {`.. i think u need to use loop here.

Comment: i tried this if($data[0] > 0 as well but still facing same issue. it check duplication and show me error. but for 2nd entry its routing me to else statement... can you or anyone, please code this for me ... thanks in advance.

Comment: your query will return one record or multiple?

Comment: writing this code for evaluation system, multiple calls can be evaluated against ID, but this code will verify either same id, cli, and duration could not be duplicated. however, if any thing like duration is changed, then it will go for next page. if all these three fields are matched in DB, it gives an error, like already existed.

Comment: than use `mysqli_num_rows()` like `$rs = mysqli_query($con,$check);
$rowCount = mysqli_num_rows($rs);
if($rowCount > 0 ) {
  echo "Record already exist";
}
else
{
  echo "Error";
}`

Comment: tried the same as you suggested. but still same problem ... check the first record but for 2nd row it's still routing to else statement.

Comment: `$check="SELECT * FROM eval WHERE empid = '$_POST[empid]' AND cli = '$_POST[cli]'  AND callduration = '$_POST[callduration]' ";` this query will return one record or two?

Comment: sorry but what is the posted value of duration in your example? If you check for a duration of 00:01:00 then with your query you will never get a record with duration 00:01:01. They are different. You need to specifiy a range interval to do the check if you want to get both records

Comment: devpro ... this query will check whole db either this record is matching with id, cli and duration. if yes then returns a error else to the new page.  moreover in this case ID, CLI can be same and duration could be different ... if can check multiple values.

Comment: Your query seems to be vulnerable to SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `mysqli_num_rows` because with `mysqli_fetch_array` you getting each record and can loop throught them. Now with `mysqli_num_rows` you're counting all records and can handle if the record exists or not.

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test");
    $query = "SELECT * 
              FROM eval
              WHERE empid = '".$_POST['empid']."' 
                  AND cli = '".$_POST['cli']."'
                  AND callduration = '".$_POST['callduration']."'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    $data = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if($data > 0 ) {
        echo "Record already exist...<br/>";
    } else {
        echo "<a href='NewUser.php'> New Sign Up </a>
    }
?>
```

As requested my test query

```
$query = "SELECT * 
          FROM user 
          WHERE user_name = '".$_POST['user_name']."'
              AND user_mail = '".$_POST['user_mail']."'";
```

Comment: What is the current result of your select?

Comment: directly going to else statement ... while same record is already exist in db

Comment: I tried it with an other query and it works fine. So I doesn't know where you're problem is

Comment: can you please share your query as well .. mine is mentioned above.

Comment: by adding my query I found the mistake in your query. You wrote `$_POST[empid]` but it have to be `$_POST['empid']`. To access a value in  `$_POST` array you have to pass the key as a string